# PHP/MySQL Query Issues

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, post, jscript

I am attempting to set up a basic log in system for a website but I am having major issues getting the query to operate correctly.  So far everything I have tried to do to figure out what is going on has failed.  As far as I can tell the query itself is not failing but it is not returning any data either.  Using the query in phpMyAdmin results in the proper query information being returned.

Here is my php code:

```
<?PHP

//Empty error variables
$sqlerror;

if(empty($_POST['uname']))
{
    $data = "false,Username field empty";
    echo json_encode($data);
    return false;
}

if (empty($_POST['pword']))
{
    $data = "false,Password field empty";
    echo json_encode($data);
    return false;
}

$username = $_POST['uname'];
$password = $_POST['pword'];

echo $username."<br/>";

echo $password."<br/>";

if(!CheckDB())
{
    $data = "false,".$sqlerror;
    echo json_encode($data);
    return false;
}

else
{
    CheckDBL();
}

function CheckDB()
{
    echo "Made it to CheckDB! <br/>";
    $connection = mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {   
        $sqlerror = "Could not log in to database";
        return false;
    }
    
    echo "Connection established! <br/>";
    mysqli_close($connection);
    return true;    
}

function CheckDBL($username,$password)
{
    echo "Made it to CheckDBL! <br/>";
    $sql =  mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
    
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Connection failed";
        return false;
    }
    
    

if ($query = mysqli_prepare($sql,"Select Password From login_info Where Username = ?"))
    {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $username);
            
        if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($query))
        {
            echo "Query failed! <br/>"; 
            echo mysqli_error($sql);
            return false;
        }
                                                        
        else
        {
            echo "Query successful <br/>";
        }
        
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query,$password2);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($query);  
                                        
        echo "The password is: ".$password2;
    }
    
    else
    {
        echo "Statement preparation failed <br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

And the output in my browser from this code:

> GWil
>
> TestPassword
>
> Made it to CheckDB!
>
> Connection established!
>
> Made it to CheckDBL!
>
> Query successful
>
> The password is:

Comment: No where in your code, do i see you getting any query information.

Comment: And what dso u want it to print? The Output seems okay?

Comment: And what do you expect here?

Comment: @u_mulder I am attempting to retrieve a test password from the database table that the code connects to based on the username supplied in a form on the index.html page of the website.  However my initial version of the code did not produce anything even though I know the code in question (not shown above in the OP, that is the frankencode that has risen from my attempt to get something to return from the database) to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database") or die (mysqli_error($connect));
mysqli_set_charset($connect,"utf8");

$username="hej";

if ($query = mysqli_prepare($connect,"Select Password From login_info Where Username =?")){

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $username);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($query)){

    echo "Query failed! <br/>"; 
    echo mysqli_error($query);
    return false;
    }else{
    echo "Query successful <br/>";
    }
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query,$password2);<br/>
mysqli_stmt_fetch($query);<br/> echo "The password is: ".$password2;<br/>
}else{
echo "Statement preparation failed";}
```

in table login_info i have username=hej and password=123

this will achive what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it is a mess due to all of the tinkering I have been trying to get it to output whatever data is being returned.  As for your suggested code change, it produced no extra information on the php page.  Same output as described in my OP.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php read on here and you will find your answer you are looking for. you should really clean up your code, becouse right now it dosent make sense really and you have prepare and execute in your connecting part?

Comment: I have followed the suggestions from that documentation page and updated the code in my OP.  Things still are not working right but it does seem like the statement is being prepared properly.

Comment: This will slove your problem, i tested it and it works. i edited my orginal answer

Comment: replace my CheckDBL code with your suggestion.  the '>' in the statement triggered a mysqli_error() line I had added to the last else in the function stating that there was a syntax error.  Removed it but still have no password being retrieved.  I am going to try the code on my own webhost because I now have the suspicion that my client's webhost has something improperly set up server side.

Comment: i missed to erase '>' at two points in the code i have removed it now and should work fine.

Comment: I figured out the problem, and it was a noob thing too.  I forgot to re-add the parameter passes to the CheckDBL call.  The webhost my client is set up with has a control panel from 2003 and a lot of features you find at other web hosters you won't be able to find with them.  Had to move the code over to my own website so I could get PHP error output and finally figured out the issue because of those.  Thanks for the suggestions though, I am sure my frakencode would have not worked either way without the refactoring/recoding for proper form.